# Restrict secondarynamenode to be installed and run on any other node in the cluster

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

---

I have a have cloudera CDH3u4 cluster setup. I have a secondarynamenode daemon running on one of the nodes.

I have to ensure that a user who has root access to a node on the cluster (for example, a datanode that does not have any other daemons running) should not be able to start an instance of secondarynamenode daemon on this node (thereby now having two secondarynamenodes on the cluster)

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this property to `hdfs-site.xml`

```
namedfs.secondary.http.address
valuesecondarynamenode-host address or ip:50090
```

Answer (score 0):

namenode will allow only that secondary node u mentioned other than that it wont allow anothe secondary namenode to checkpoint it